# WCF error while working with List, ErrorCode: 10054

Tags: c#, wcf

WCF error while working with List:

> "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing
>   connection was forcibly closed by the remote host"
>    while trying to return a List in from WCF Service.

note please;
 1. my business object Bank is set as KnownTypeAttribute like `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(ProjectName.Bo.Bank))]`

1. I can return object Bank from WCF Service
2. my inner exception error hierarchy is like
   Exception: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a  receive.

InnerException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

InnerException:An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

1. i tried with `[ServiceKnownType(typeof(System.Collections.IList))]`

in short i am getting error while while WCF client trying to receive `return List<Bank>` please any body have some suggestion?

Comment: I think you need to start off with [Tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)

Comment: If your Bank class is an Entity Framework object try to create a simple POCO of Bank populate it and return the POCO object. Also make sure that the List<Bank> is not very large and if it is very large then increase the readerQuotas settings on both client and server side for your binding.

Answer (score 0):

not realy sure about it, but shouldnt you use generic interface when returning generic class? [IList<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6) instead of IList..

Answer (score 0):

solved!! it was a ServiceKnownType problem. in known type loader we have to add runtime Type like;

```
Type aaa =  Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[ProjectName.BusinessObjects.Bank, ProjectName.BusinessObjects, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]");
```

knownTypes.Add(aaa);

anyone having same problem can try this. its working in my environment!!